# How do I use Gold Bond (Ad) item?

Tags: danmachi-memoria-freese

[image]

So I got this item from an event exchange, and I tried to use it and saw that it's fir a 3 star adventurer, so I went to rank up a 3 star to the point of limit break and it still won't work, not even an option to use the item. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: are you sure you built up an adventurer and not an assist?

Comment: It should be able to be used in place of a bond when you don't have a bond for that unit. I have the bond but I don't have anyone to use it on to test it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to a 3 star hero you wish to limit break, choose limit break, and then choose "Use Item".

[image]